# Can I visit various colleges in the US without a visa to find out more about them?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-free-entry

I'm visiting the east coast to visit a few colleges and their labs. I am planning to apply to graduate school. I want to know if I can tell the border patrol officer this if applying for entry under the VWP?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend fabricating a cover story.  Always answer the questions of border officers truthfully;  if they ask for the purpose of your visit, you should tell them.

Comment: Beyond this, it would help to know what your citizenship is, and what kind of visa you'll be entering the US on (if you need one.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert OP's a VWP national

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Enter visa-free, visit the colleges (which is allowed), then apply and return home to obtain an F-1 visa, with which you can re-enter.
2. Get a B2 "prospective student" visa, with which you don't have to exit and re-enter the US, but can [apply for a change of status](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539), which however costs $370. The next time you travel abroad (except to Canada, Mexico, Bermuda or the Caribbean for less than 30 days), you have to get an F-1 visa from the local US Embassy before re-entering (make sure to have your I-20 for this)